# Getting Nagios on an Ubuntu server to talk to NSClient++ running on Windows server on a WAN

Tags: windows, linux-networking, nagios, ssh-tunnel

I have installed freeSSHD on my Windows machine, created a user, enabled tunneling, copied over a public rsa key, and installed NSClient++. On my Nagios server, I have Nagios running and a Windows.cfg file that looks correct.

I am able to ssh from the nagios box to the windows box with the following:

ssh user@windows-box-ipaddr

and

ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:1433:windows-box-ipaddr:1433 administrator@windows-box-ipaddr

Despite this, I'm seeing errors such as these in Nagios:

**connect to address 127.0.0.1 and port 12489: Connection refused**

I am not sure what IP address needs to go in the windows.cfg for the define host, nor am I sure what the NSClient++ IP should be set to.

What I do know for certain is that I can get this servers to connect through SSH. I am thinking that I should be using another port or perhaps I need to open many ports in the firewall. At this point I am at a standstill.

Comment: what are you trying to do, exactly? and why does it involve ssh tunneling?

Comment: Keith, I am trying to monitor a Windows server that is not on our network. Either a VPN or SSH tunnel appear to be the most effective ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

NSCLient++ by default uses port 12489, as the error message reports.

Try

```
ssh -f -N -L 12489:localhost:12489 administrator@windows-box
```

Of course this requires that NSClient++ is actually running and listening on that port. Your command would forward port 1433 - where did you get that port number?

Comment: Some bum docs I read... It's working now thank you. I am trying to get Tomcat and Apache to show up now...

Comment: Is there a way to monitor apache and Tomcat?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question, after using the site search. And if this answer solves your problem, please accept it (see the [help] to learn about how the site works).